# Property setter gives an error in Python

Tags: python, properties

I am new to Python. I am try to learn the @property decorator in Python. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class C(object):
    """docstring for C"""
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self._foo = foo

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo
    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value

        return self.foo


c = C(1)

print c.foo

print c.foo(2)
```

In the above code first `print` gave me "1". When I try to set the value to foo, it gives the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sub.py", line 23, in <module>
    print c.foo(2)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

How to solve this error. What's wrong my code?

Comment: [Read the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) properly.
*`c.x` will invoke the getter, `c.x = value` will invoke the **setter** and del c.x the deleter.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A setter is used with the assignment operator `=`:

```
c.foo = 2
```

A further example how `c.foo(2)` works:

```
In [7]: c = C(lambda x: x*x)

In [8]: c.foo(2)
Out[8]: 4
```

`c.foo(…)` first *gets* the value in `c.foo`, then invokes the function.

Comment: Thanks @Kay. Why it is working this way ?. What's wrong with this c.foo(2) ?.

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean to do

```
c.foo = 2
```

You use properties like you would attributes.